# Chrome Jump List gone on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, jumplist

Image looks like this:

[image: 1]

Chrome's jumplist won't show so there are no "New tab" or "New incognito tab" options. I want to blame CCleaner because it clears recent jump lists, but somehow I doubt this is the problem. This question has been posted many times on the Google product forums and the solution was to delete these folders:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\
```

Only problem is they don't exist. They aren't hidden either. Another solution was to delete `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User`. This also didn't work. I've tried reinstalling, manually removing all registry keys, restarting. Nothing works, and it's really getting on my nerves. What do I do?

Comment: did you confirm ALL instances (namely background ones are stopped before reloading/ re-installing)?

Comment: Yes I absolutely did.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to tell which version of Chrome you're using. Did the jumplist disappear after an update or without any apparent cause?

Comment: It occurs with both chrome 40 and 42. Updating didn't break it, so I think it has something to do with windows itself. I was about to shut down my computer but stopped to properly close a program then I noticed the jumplist was gone.

Comment: ...and hasn't come back.

Comment: Do jumplists not show up for all programs? If that's not the case looks to me like a Chrome-specific issue. Did you ensure all files and registry keys related to Chrome were gone after you uninstalled? Some reg key or file might have possibly got corrupted and perhaps the uninstaller failed to remove it.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your desktop, not Chrome. Did you try deleting that shortcut, then just add it again, or use the start menu.

Comment: Yes also did that. I just restored my computer because this issue isn't solvable.

Answer (score -2):

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\
```

Those folders are probably in `ROAMING` folder

They are hidden even if u enable "show hiden folder and files" and "show system files" (at least on my Win8) only if u know the patch can u acces them so they would be :
[userfolder]\Appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\

What u need to do is delete the folder. Look it up on google or make a .bat file and paste the code below and run

```
:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.eightforums.com
:: Tutorial:  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9611-jump-lists-reset-clear-windows-8-a.html


del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*

del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*

del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe
```

Worked for me.

P.S. I wanted to add my drives pinned and have custom shortcuts but M$ didnt make it easy to customize and i did break it.

Comment: Have you confirmed where the folder is, because your comment is written in such a way, you sound like you have not even verified where the folder actually is.  If you navigate to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\` what that expands to is easy enough to verify and indicate in your answer.